# Is Binary XCFramework ready to use with old swift versions?

Tags: xcframework

We're building a new binary framework for iOS (and macOS later). However, we're thinking of building it in Swift, and after some research, and [WWDC talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/416/), I still missing some details:

1. Will we be able to ship it to apps:

   - using old Swift versions? (e.g. Swift 2)
   - using Objective-C?
2. We know that cocoapods 1.9 supports XCFramework, but it's still in beta, how do you think we should distribute the framwork?
3. If XCFramework is not mature enough yet, is the only option now to use the old `.framework` using Objective-C?

Thank you and looking for your suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion:

1. No. This is not possible. It will only work for Swift versions>5.1.
2. For now, I would suggest waiting for a stable release before shifting to xcframeworks. I feel there are still quite a few bugs and uncertainties around this for now. Until then, you can distribute this as a [fat framework](https://medium.com/allatoneplace/writing-custom-universal-framework-in-xcode-9-and-ios-11-7a63a2ce024a).
3. You can build .framework using swift too and then distribute as a fat framework as mentioned above.

Hope it helps :)